# Mode change programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to change phone mode programmatically, i.e., turn on or off Airplane mode programmatically? If so, could you please provide some resources to get a clearer concept of it?

as it is not possible on wear Os, so qurious mind wants to know is it possible in mobile phone or not ?

Comment: You cant do this on a non rooted device afaik

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Android can manipulate these variables only. This is why applications would ask for you to tun on your location instead of the app just doing it.